# ListService.getListItemcompleted Event in BackgroundWorker's doWork Event not working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, outlook

I am doing outlook 2007 vsto programming with SharePoint Server 2007.

Now problem is that as I am calling `getListItemAsync` asynchronously so the `GetListItemItem` completed event is not firing.So the `ListItemCompleted` method is not being executed.

I have changed the code `getlistitemasync` to `getlistitem` but as `getlistitemcomepleted` event is not being executed so `listitemcompleted` method is not being executed and therefore I can not update the gridview of the user control of the custom taskpane.

I need to run this code syncronously.do you have any solution so that I can register the list service's `getlistItemCompletedEvent`?

This is my code which is running in BackGroundWorker's doWork event.

```
private void GetListItemsAsyncWrapper(string m_uploadDocLibraryName, string viewname, XmlNode ndQuery, XmlNode ndViewFields, string rowlimit, XmlNode ndQueryOptions, string webid, object uploadData, CommonProperties property)
{
    try
    {

    // for 2007//
    ListWebService.Lists listService = new ListWebService.Lists();
    listService.Credentials = property.Credentionals;
    listService.Url = property.CopyServiceURL;
    listService.GetListItemsCompleted += new ListWebService.GetListItemsCompletedEventHandler(listService_GetListItemsCompleted);
    // listService.GetListItemsAsync(m_uploadDocLibraryName, null, ndQuery, ndViewFields, "2", ndQueryOptions, null, uploadData);

    XmlNode n = listService.GetListCollection();


    string urlroot = property.LibSite.Remove(property.LibSite.Length - 1);
    foreach (XmlNode item in n.ChildNodes)
    {
        string strcompare = urlroot + item.Attributes["DefaultViewUrl"].Value;
        if (strcompare == property.CompletedoclibraryURL)
        {
            m_uploadDocLibraryName = item.Attributes["Title"].Value;
            cmproperties.UploadDocLibraryName = m_uploadDocLibraryName;
            break;

        }

    }

    listService.GetListItemsAsync(m_uploadDocLibraryName, null, ndQuery, ndViewFields, "2", ndQueryOptions, null, uploadData);
    //listService.GetListItems(m_uploadDocLibraryName, null, ndQuery, ndViewFields, "2", ndQueryOptions, null);
    UploadItemsData senduploadData = (UserModule.UploadItemsData)uploadData;
                }
catch (Exception ex)
{
}

}


/// <summary>
/// <c>listService_GetListItemsCompleted</c> event handler
/// calls <c>ListItemCompleted</c> method
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
void listService_GetListItemsCompleted(object sender, SharePoint_Link07.ListWebService.GetListItemsCompletedEventArgs e)
{

try
{
    XmlNode xmlnode = e.Result;
    UploadItemsData uploaditemdata = (UploadItemsData)e.UserState;
    ListItemCompleted(xmlnode, uploaditemdata);

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    m_isUploadingCompleted = true;
    DelegateUpdateGridRow pdSteps = new DelegateUpdateGridRow(UpdataGridRows);
    this.Invoke(pdSteps, new object[] { false, "uploaded with error", "", null });

    EncodingAndDecoding.ShowMessageBox("Error occured, may be th document Library does not exists", "Error occured, may be th document Library does not exists", MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}


}

/// <summary>
/// <c>ListItemCompleted</c> function
/// gets uploaded file  url and calls <c>UpdataGridRows</c> method to  add new row in grid.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="ndvolListItem"></param>
/// <param name="uitemdata"></param>
public void ListItemCompleted(XmlNode ndvolListItem, UploadItemsData uitemdata)
{
try
{


    XmlNode ndVolunteerListItems = ndvolListItem;
    string test = uitemdata.UploadFileName;
    if (ndVolunteerListItems != null)
    {

        if (ndVolunteerListItems.ChildNodes.Count == 3)
        {

            if (ndVolunteerListItems.ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes.Count > 1)
            {
                string id = Convert.ToString(ndVolunteerListItems.ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[1].Attributes["ows_ID"].Value);
                //////////

                UpdateItemAttributes(id, uitemdata);

                //////////

                string sucessURL1 = m_LibSite + m_uploadFolderNode.ChildNodes[3].InnerText + "/Forms/EditForm.aspx?ID=" + id + "&UpFName=" + uitemdata.UploadFileName; ;
                m_isUploadingCompleted = true;
                UpdataGridRows(true, "Success", sucessURL1, uitemdata);

                UploadItemsData item = uitemdata; //(UploadItemsData)e.UserState;


                //try
                //{
                //    string fileCheckin = m_sharepointLibraryURL.Substring(0, m_sharepointLibraryURL.LastIndexOf("Forms")) + item.UploadFileName;
                //    bool b = listService.CheckInFile(fileCheckin, "Uplaod Completed.", "1");
                //}
                //catch (Exception ex)
                //{ 
                //}
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string outMessage1 = ex.Message;
    if (ex.InnerException != null)
    {
        outMessage1 = ex.InnerException.Message;
    }
    m_isUploadingCompleted = true;
    DelegateUpdateGridRow pdSteps = new DelegateUpdateGridRow(UpdataGridRows);
    this.Invoke(pdSteps, new object[] { false, "Exception in GetListItemsCompleted Event." + outMessage1, " ", uitemdata });
}
}
```